# ¿Como puedo insertar varios datos a mi base de datos usando el plugin Select2 con codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select2

Estoy creando un sistema en PHP usando Codeigniter, quiero registrar varios datos en una tabla utilizando un select multiple y el plugin select2. El problema es que de los datos que selecciono, solo el último es el que se registra en mi base de datos. ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

**Este es el formulario**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="form-label" for="multiple-basic">
       grupos
   </label>
   <select class="select2 form-control" name="grupos[]"  multiple="multiple" id="multiple-basic">
       <optgroup label="GRUPOS REGISTRADOS">              
        <?php foreach ($group_data as $k => $v): ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $v['id_grupo'] ?>"><?php echo  strtoupper($v['nombre_grupo']) ?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
       </optgroup>
   </select>
</div>

$('.select2').select2({
    tokenSeparators: [','],
    tags: true,
    multiple: true,
    maximumSelectionLength: 2,
    placeholder: "Select maximum 20 items"
});
```

### El controlador

```
<?php
  public function createSingle(){
        $response= array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());        
            $oidVal = implode(",", $this->input->post('grupos'));
            $data = array(
                'id_usuario'=> $this->session->userdata('id_usuario'),
                'id_grupo'=> $oidVal);
            $create = $this->model_users->createSingle($data);
       if($create== true) {
                $response['success'] = true;
                $response['messages'] = 'DATOS REGISTRADOS:';
            }else {
                $response['success'] = false;
                $response['messages'] = 'ERROR AL REGISTRAR LOS DATOS';
            }

             echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

### El modelo

```
<?php
    public function createSingle($data=''){
        if($data) {
            $create = $this->db->insert('registro_grupos_usuarios', $data);
            return ($create == true) ? true : false;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder procesar los datos de un **select multiple** en el controlador debes de recorrer el **GET** como un **array()**.

Vas a reemplazar esto:

```
$oidVal = implode(",", $this->input->post('grupos'));
$data = array('id_usuario' => $this->session->userdata('id_usuario'),
              'id_grupo'   => $oidVal);
$create = $this->model_users->createSingle($data);
```

Por esto:

```
foreach ($this->input->post('grupos') as $option){
    $data = array('id_usuario' => $this->session->userdata('id_usuario'),
                  'id_grupo'   => $option);
    $create = $this->model_users->createSingle($data);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Eduardo, me ha funcionado, y ya se registran todos los datos seleccionados en la base de datos. Gracias por resolverme el problema.